# Codeigniter custom meta description for groups

Tags: codeigniter

First of all sorry for the question, I'm not familiar with php, but I have spent 4 days struggling and reading similar threats, and now I need your help:

I have bought a website created with codeigniter that has a **global** site_head, the meta description is defined like this:

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<?=$description?>">
```

and the description variable is replaced with the title of the post - for groups (categories) and single pages.

I have created additional row in the groups (categories) table with php my admin - called " my_meta_desc" 
at the view folder when I enter : `<?=$group['my_meta_desc']?>` - my meta description is displaying as it should be, but I have my_meta_desc only for categories and if I replace

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<?=$description?>">
```

with

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<?=$group['my_meta_desc']?>">
```

All pages except categories will be with blank description.

**Is it possible to have some if funciton - defining if it is used groups/images.php (this is a view file) to use `<?=$group['my_meta_desc']?>` and for everything else `<?=$description?>` - at the site_head.php ?**

---

From my research the description is defined at models file called template.php at the models folder:

```
    if(empty($desc)) $desc = $site_info['meta_description'];
    $data['description'] = $desc;
```

The $site_info['meta_description'] - is the meta description for the index page and used only there (and of course all pages without meta description)

I just can't find where $desc is defined - any clues? - because as I have already explained for single pages meta description is the post title - included at database table - '*images*' row '*text*' and for categories it is at database table '*groups*' row '*name*'

There is a group controller but it does not include anything related to $desk or $description .

### I'll appreciate any suggestions

Template.php - situated at models folder:

```
   function Load($file,$data,$title,$type='public',$desc='',$block_index=0){
    global $admin_row, $user_row, $lang_array, $l, $lf, $site_info, $sidebar_groups_inc;

    if(!isset($sidebar_groups_inc)){
        $sidebar_groups_inc = array();
    }
    $data['sidebar_groups'] =  $sidebar_groups_inc;

    if($type == 'admin'){
        $title = "Админ Панел - ".$title;
    }

    if($type == 'public'){
        $languages = $lang_array;

        $data['languages'] = $languages;

        if($user_row['login'] == 1){
            $data['nf_header']=array();
            $get = imysql_adapted_query("select notifications.*, timediff(concat(curdate(), ' ', curtime()), concat(date)) as hours from notifications where user = '".$user_row['id']."' order by `read` asc, id desc limit 0,5");
            if($get){
                while($row = imysql_adapted_fetch_array($get)){
                    $data['nf_header'][] = $row;
                }
            }

            foreach($data['nf_header'] as $val){
                if($val['read'] == 0) {
                    $data['mark_notifications'][] = $val['id'];
                }
            }

        }

        $data['pages']=array();
        $get_pages = imysql_adapted_query("select id, name_".$lf." as name from pages where cat = '3' order by id asc");
        if($get_pages){
            while($row = imysql_adapted_fetch_array($get_pages)) {
                $data['pages'][] = $row;
            }
        }

    }

    $data['title'] = $this->Title($title);
    $data['file'] = $type."/".$file;
    $data['admin'] = $admin_row;
    $data['user'] = $user_row;
    //      $data['path'] = $data['path'];

    if(empty($key)) $key = $site_info['meta_keywords'];

    if(empty($desc)) $desc = $site_info['meta_description'];
    $data['description'] = $desc;
    $data['keywords'] = $key;
    $data['block_index'] = $block_index;



    $data['data'] = $data; // TODO: Fix the need for this shitty reference !!!
    $this->load->view($type.'/site_head',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<?php echo isset($group['my_meta_desc']) ? $group['my_meta_desc'] : $description ?>">
```

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for the sugestion, but this made all descriptions blank except for groups that have description, and also removed the description on all subpages for these groups and replace it with the my_meta_desc

Comment: i think you should revise your question for clarity. you make a lot of assumptions about what might be happening and also make the assumption that we are familiar with your app/schema. keep it simple and include the relevant parts of code (in this case the template file that generates the header).

Comment: I have included thewhole function from template.php from the models folder. Maybe if it is possible to have if function for example: if is loaded a view template from /groups/images - to use my description

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've figured it out:

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<? if($groups){  echo  $group['my_meta_desc'];
     } else {
      echo $description;} ?>">
```